# I do not get the tool as I am in phase 5. in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

When I get to phase 5 wing, it does not give me the tool "GasterBlaster". How can I fix it? This is the script:

```lua
elseif kills == P5R then
    HRP.Phase4Music:Destroy()
    char.Highlight:Destroy()
    char.LineEffect:Destroy()
    HRP.LineEffect2:Destroy()
    HRP.Ring:Destroy()
    HRP.Ring2:Destroy()
    HRP.Iner:Destroy()

    char.Head.Overhead.Label.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(242, 255, 0)

    local clonedMusic = phase5.Phase5Music:Clone()
    local ClonedHighlight = phase5.Highlight:Clone()
    local ClonedPT = phase5.Armstron1:Clone()
    local ClonedBlF = phase5.Armstron2:Clone()
    local ClonedBF = phase5.Armstron3:Clone()
    local ClonedDBF = phase5.Debris:Clone()
    local ClonedPF = phase5.Debris2:Clone()
    local ClonedPS = phase5.Flesha:Clone()

    clonedMusic.Parent = HRP
    clonedMusic:Play()
    ClonedHighlight.Parent = char
    ClonedPT.Parent = HRP
    ClonedBlF.Parent = HRP
    ClonedBF.Parent = HRP
    ClonedDBF.Parent = HRP
    ClonedPF.Parent = HRP
    ClonedPS.Parent = HRP
    local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
    local Players = game:GetService("Players")
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local backpack = player:FindFirstChild("Backpack")
    if not backpack then
        backpack = Instance.new("Backpack")
        backpack.Name = "Backpack"
        backpack.Parent = player
    end
    local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("DeliverGasterBlasterTool")
    if not remoteEvent then
        remoteEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
        remoteEvent.Name = "DeliverGasterBlasterTool"
        remoteEvent.Parent = ReplicatedStorage
    end

    remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
        local gasterBlasterTool = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Items"):FindFirstChild("GasterBlaster")

        if gasterBlasterTool and backpack then
            local clonedTool = gasterBlasterTool:Clone()
            clonedTool.Parent = backpack
        else
            -- Manejar el caso en el que no se encuentre la herramienta o la mochila
        end
    end)

    local userInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
    userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, isProcessed)
        if isProcessed then
            return
        end
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
            remoteEvent:FireServer(player)
        end
    end)
```

I have tried to activate the remote event by pressing the letter E to get the tool.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if u gave me the complete code as there is an elseif in the beginning and also i cant tell what alot of the varablies are, but their are issues with the input service

using

```
if isProcessed then
    return
end
```

returns the given value is there is any but it also ends the code, u might wanna change it to sumthing like this

```
while true do
if isProcessed then
break
end
end
```

and `remoteEvent:FireServer(player)` can only be used on local scripts and also u cant set the player parameter, it returns the player/client the event been fired from automatically so u just need `remoteEvent:FireServer()`.

```
if not remoteEvent then
        remoteEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
        remoteEvent.Name = "DeliverGasterBlasterTool"
        remoteEvent.Parent = ReplicatedStorage
    end
```

u also create the remote event in studio in replicated storage dont have a script do it.

and finally this need to be a in a script, put it in server script service in studio

```
remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
        local gasterBlasterTool = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Items"):FindFirstChild("GasterBlaster")

        if gasterBlasterTool and backpack then
            local clonedTool = gasterBlasterTool:Clone()
            clonedTool.Parent = backpack
        else
            -- Manejar el caso en el que no se encuentre la herramienta o la mochila
        end
    end)
```

alot of this code needs to be in a local script besides the part that i said goes into the server